# Apex interactive report embedded in outlook email

Tags: oracle, email, outlook, report, embed

I want to have an Apex interactive report embedded in outlook email..does anybody know how I can do that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

With Best Regards
F.S

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to do that. You can't really do a form submit back to the server in an email, nor can you do Javascript. Without either of those things, you don't really have a very interactive report.

You could add a link to your page with the interactive report, though.

Comment: Can I create an excel spreadsheet from the interactive report and embed it in mailto body..Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Try this blog for creating .CSV file: http://spendolini.blogspot.com/2006/04/custom-export-to-csv.html